# How to add icon in httpd.config file

Tags: apache

I referred this: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html#addicon, But unable to view the icon, this is what I am able to see:
[image]

The above is the Screenshot in Chrome Browser and even in other browsers I am able to see this broken image. The code what I have written in httpd.config:

```
DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs"
<Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs">
    Options +Indexes
    IndexOptions +FancyIndexing
    IndexOptions +HTMLTable
    IndexOptions +NameWidth=* 
    
    AddIcon ${SRVROOT}/icons/text.gif .pl

    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Can anyone please tell me how to display the image properly and also remove the "[ ]" brackets too which is beside the broken image. I am using Apache HTTP Server version 2.4, Thank you !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just Uncomment the line `Include conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf`  in httpd.conf file and it worked.